Help understanding a proof about trace preserving and positive operators.
Edit: Going to try to make this better.
The implications (i) -> (ii) and (i) -> (iii) are clear to me. I'm not quite sure where the positive operators come from in (ii) -> (iii), but I had someone talk me through it and I'm looking at their notes trying to understand...feeling cautiously optimistic. The opening statement of the proof of (iii) -> (ii) is sadly opaque to me, and I'm finding it quite a roadblock as there doesn't seem to be much to get your hands on.
My attempt at understanding where the highlighted statement comes from:
I believe $0 \leq A \leq B$ with $\operatorname{Tr}(A) = \operatorname{Tr}(B)$ implies $A = B$, so since $\operatorname{Tr}_A$ preserves traces, then $\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E} \leq I_{H_B}$ or the reverse inequality would imply $\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E} = I_{H_B}$ I think? But I don't see how that helps, or indeed which, if either, of those inequalities hold.
I did just notice that $\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A}$ is not defined, sorry that was an oversight on my part.
Would really appreciate any hints or any explanation of what is happening, I am not really comfortable with operators yet.
Just lmk if this still doesn't meet guidelines and I'll take it down.
End of edit.

Could anyone help me understand the indicated line in the following proof? I'm just not seeing it. Can post my rough work if people would like, just don't feel like typing it out unless necessary.
Paper here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0504189



Note that for $\sigma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$, $\text{Tr}(\sigma) = \text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A} \sigma P_\mathfrak{A}) + \text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \sigma P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp)$. Also note that by linearity, (3) holds for all $\sigma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B)$. Thus, from (3), we have,
$$\begin{split}
\text{Tr}((\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E})(\sigma)) &= \text{Tr}((\text{Tr}_A \circ \mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E})(\sigma))\\
&= \text{Tr}(\text{Tr}_A(\sigma))\\
&= \text{Tr}(\sigma)\\
&= \text{Tr}(\mathcal{E}(\sigma))\\
&= \text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A} \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}) + \text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp)\\
&= \text{Tr}((\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E})(\sigma)) + \text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp)
\end{split}$$
Whence $\text{Tr}(P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp) = 0$ for all $\sigma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B)$. In particular, when $\sigma$ is positive, since $\mathcal{E}(\sigma)$ and thus $P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp$ are positive, we have $P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp = 0$, i.e.,
$$(\mathcal{E}(\sigma)^{1/2} P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp)^\ast(\mathcal{E}(\sigma)^{1/2} P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp) = P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp = 0$$
So $\mathcal{E}(\sigma)^{1/2} P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp = 0$ and thus $\mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}^\perp = 0$, i.e., $\mathcal{E}(\sigma) = \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A}$. Taking adjoints yields $\mathcal{E}(\sigma) = P_\mathfrak{A} \mathcal{E}(\sigma)$, so,
$$\mathcal{E}(\sigma) = P_\mathfrak{A} \mathcal{E}(\sigma) = P_\mathfrak{A} \mathcal{E}(\sigma) P_\mathfrak{A} = (\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E})(\sigma)$$
For all positive $\sigma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B)$. Linearity then implies $\mathcal{E}(\sigma) = (\mathcal{P}_\mathfrak{A} \circ \mathcal{E})(\sigma)$ for all $\sigma \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}^A \otimes \mathcal{H}^B)$, in particular $\sigma \in \mathfrak{A}$.

Thank you so, so very much! It's a boring question, I know.
